# How to arrange a table in ascending order in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I wanted to make a table that gets arranged in ascending order. Here it what I did currently:

```
//@version=5
indicator("high_and_positive_sorted", overlay = true)


//Step 1: taking inputs
u01 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's01')
u02 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's02')
u03 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's03')
u04 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's04')
u05 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's05')
u06 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's06')
u07 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's07')
u08 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's08')
u09 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's09')
u10 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's10')
u11 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's11')
u12 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's12')
u13 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's13')


s01 = input.symbol('CNXMEDIA', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's01')
s02 = input.symbol('CNXREALTY', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's02')
s03 = input.symbol('CNXPSUBANK', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's03')
s04 = input.symbol('CNXIT', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's04')
s05 = input.symbol('CNXFMCG', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's05')
s06 = input.symbol('CNXENERGY', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's06')
s07 = input.symbol('CNXPHARMA', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's07')
s08 = input.symbol('CNXAUTO', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's08')
s09 = input.symbol('NIFTY', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's09')
s10 = input.symbol('BANKNIFTY', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's10')
s11 = input.symbol('NIFTYPVTBANK', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's11')
s12 = input.symbol('CNXFINANCE', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's12')
s13 = input.symbol('CNXMETAL', group = 'Symbols', inline = 's13')

only_symbol(s) => 
    array.get(str.split(s, ":"), 1)


perc_change = (close - open)*100/open

var candle_color = 0
candle_color := close > open ? 1 : close < open ? -1 : 0 


screener_func() =>
    perc_change 




high_low_func() =>
    candle_color 

col_width = input.float(1, title = "Column Width (%)")
scr_numb  = input.int(1, title = "Screen #", tooltip = '1 - rightmost screener', minval = 1)

rsi01 = request.security(s01, timeframe.period, screener_func())
rsi02 = request.security(s02, timeframe.period, screener_func())
rsi03 = request.security(s03, timeframe.period, screener_func())
rsi04 = request.security(s04, timeframe.period, screener_func())
rsi05 = request.security(s05, timeframe.period, screener_func())
rsi06 = request.security(s06, timeframe.period, screener_func())
rsi07 = request.security(s07, timeframe.period, screener_func())
rsi08 = request.security(s08, timeframe.period, screener_func())
rsi09 = request.security(s09, timeframe.period, screener_func())
rsi10 = request.security(s10, timeframe.period, screener_func())
rsi11 = request.security(s11, timeframe.period, screener_func())
rsi12 = request.security(s12, timeframe.period, screener_func())
rsi13 = request.security(s13, timeframe.period, screener_func())

hl01 = request.security(s01, timeframe.period, high_low_func())
hl02 = request.security(s02, timeframe.period, high_low_func())
hl03 = request.security(s03, timeframe.period, high_low_func())
hl04 = request.security(s04, timeframe.period, high_low_func())
hl05 = request.security(s05, timeframe.period, high_low_func())
hl06 = request.security(s06, timeframe.period, high_low_func())
hl07 = request.security(s07, timeframe.period, high_low_func())
hl08 = request.security(s08, timeframe.period, high_low_func())
hl09 = request.security(s09, timeframe.period, high_low_func())
hl10 = request.security(s10, timeframe.period, high_low_func())
hl11 = request.security(s11, timeframe.period, high_low_func())
hl12 = request.security(s12, timeframe.period, high_low_func())
hl13 = request.security(s13, timeframe.period, high_low_func())


////////////
// ARRAYS //

s_arr   = array.new_string(0)
u_arr   = array.new_bool(0)
rsi_arr = array.new_float(0)
hl_arr = array.new_float(0)
// Add Symbols 
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s01))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s02))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s03))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s04))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s05))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s06))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s07))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s08))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s09))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s10))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s11))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s12))
array.push(s_arr, only_symbol(s13))



// FLAGS 
array.push(u_arr, u01)
array.push(u_arr, u02)
array.push(u_arr, u03)
array.push(u_arr, u04)
array.push(u_arr, u05)
array.push(u_arr, u06)
array.push(u_arr, u07)
array.push(u_arr, u08)
array.push(u_arr, u09)
array.push(u_arr, u10)
array.push(u_arr, u11)
array.push(u_arr, u12)
array.push(u_arr, u13)

// RSI 
array.push(hl_arr, hl01)
array.push(hl_arr, hl02)
array.push(hl_arr, hl03)
array.push(hl_arr, hl04)
array.push(hl_arr, hl05)
array.push(hl_arr, hl06)
array.push(hl_arr, hl07)
array.push(hl_arr, hl08)
array.push(hl_arr, hl09)
array.push(hl_arr, hl10)
array.push(hl_arr, hl11)
array.push(hl_arr, hl12)
array.push(hl_arr, hl13)


///high/low push
array.push(rsi_arr, rsi01)
array.push(rsi_arr, rsi02)
array.push(rsi_arr, rsi03)
array.push(rsi_arr, rsi04)
array.push(rsi_arr, rsi05)
array.push(rsi_arr, rsi06)
array.push(rsi_arr, rsi07)
array.push(rsi_arr, rsi08)
array.push(rsi_arr, rsi09)
array.push(rsi_arr, rsi10)
array.push(rsi_arr, rsi11)
array.push(rsi_arr, rsi12)
array.push(rsi_arr, rsi13)

 
var tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 4, 41, frame_color=#151715, frame_width=1, border_width=2, border_color=color.new(color.white, 100))

if barstate.islast

    table.cell(tbl, 0, 0, 'Symbol',  width = col_width,     text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
    table.cell(tbl, 1, 0, '% change',     width = col_width,     text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
    table. Cell(tbl, 2, 0, 'positive/negative',     width = col_width,     text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
    if (scr_numb > 1)
        table.cell(tbl, 3, 0,  '',       width = col_width * 2 * (scr_numb - 1), text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.new(color.gray, 100), text_size = size.small)


    for i = 0 to 12
        if array.get(u_arr, i)
            
            
        
            rsi_col  = array.get(hl_arr, i) == 1  ? color.green :  array.get(hl_arr, i) == -1  ? color.red    : #aaaaaa 
        
            table.cell(tbl, 0, i + 1, array.get(s_arr, i),                                 text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
            table.cell(tbl, 1, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(rsi_arr, i), "#.##"),         text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.gray,    text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
            table.cell(tbl, 2, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(hl_arr, i), "#.##"),         text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = rsi_col,    text_color = color.white, text_size = size. Small)
```

I want the table to get arranged as per increasing % change.
I tried using array. Sort but it is messing up the table.

So, I need help at this : arrange the stocks as per increasing % change (and the name of stocks should change as well)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the `array.sort_indices` function. Here is an example on how to use it from QuantNomad. The script is pretty straight forward and easy to read

```
//@version=5
indicator("2 arrays", overlay = true)
 
rsi1 = request.security('AAPL', timeframe.period, ta.rsi(close, 14))
rsi2 = request.security('DIS',  timeframe.period, ta.rsi(close, 14))
rsi3 = request.security('MSFT', timeframe.period, ta.rsi(close, 14))
rsi4 = request.security('V',    timeframe.period, ta.rsi(close, 14))
rsi5 = request.security('TSLA', timeframe.period, ta.rsi(close, 14))
 
tsi1 = request.security('AAPL', timeframe.period, ta.tsi(close, 13, 25))
tsi2 = request.security('DIS',  timeframe.period, ta.tsi(close, 13, 25))
tsi3 = request.security('MSFT', timeframe.period, ta.tsi(close, 13, 25))
tsi4 = request.security('V',    timeframe.period, ta.tsi(close, 13, 25))
tsi5 = request.security('TSLA', timeframe.period, ta.tsi(close, 13, 25))
 
symbols = array.from('AAPL', 'DIS', 'MSFT', 'V', 'TSLA')
 
rsi_arr = array.from(rsi1, rsi2, rsi3, rsi4, rsi5)
tsi_arr = array.from(tsi1, tsi2, tsi3, tsi4, tsi5)
 
sorted_index = array.sort_indices(rsi_arr)
 
var tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 3, 6, frame_width  = 1, border_width = 1, border_color = #696969)
 
if barstate.islast
    table.clear(tbl, 0, 0, 2, 5)
 
    table.cell(tbl, 0, 0, text = 'Symbol', text_color = color.white, bgcolor = #696969)
    table.cell(tbl, 1, 0, text = 'RSI',    text_color = color.white, bgcolor = #696969)
    table.cell(tbl, 2, 0, text = 'TSI',    text_color = color.white, bgcolor = #696969)
 
    for i = 0 to array.size(symbols) - 1
        si = array.get(sorted_index, i)
        table.cell(tbl, 0, i + 1, text = str.tostring(array.get(symbols, si)), text_color = color.white, bgcolor = #696969)
        table.cell(tbl, 1, i + 1, text = str.tostring(math.round(array.get(rsi_arr, si), 2)), text_color = color.white, bgcolor = #aaaaaa)
        table.cell(tbl, 2, i + 1, text = str.tostring(math.round(array.get(tsi_arr, si), 2)), text_color = color.white, bgcolor = #aaaaaa)
```